# Login com facebook no Xamarin Forms com Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: c#, xamarin, microsoft-azure, xamarin-forms

Estou construindo um app(com **xamarin.forms pcl**), onde tenho um login com facebook, utilizando o *Azure Mobile Client SDK*. É possível realizar a autenticação, porem, logo após a autenticação, eu tento fazer uma listagem na url da api: https://adoteumamigo.azurewebsites.net/api/Tipo e tenho o retorno 401 Unauthorized.

Sendo que o login com a rede social foi realizado com sucesso. 
Segue as evidências:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código onde tenho o problema:

```
public async Task<List<Tipo>> GetTipoAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{BaseUrl}Tipo").ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tipo>>(
                        await new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**Observação:** Antes de colocar a autenticação com facebook, o acesso a api e o get dos dados para listagem funcionava corretamente.  O problema é porque está dando esse acesso sem autorização na url, mesmo após estar logado.
**Observação 2:** É possível testar a api no browser, com a autenticação do facebook, e a mesma funciona corretamente.

Comment: Está utilizando a classe `MobileServiceClient` para autenticação no Facebook?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Estou sim. A authenticação funciona, logo no facebook, o MobileServiceCliente me retorna o sid e o token. Agora pela manhã andei pesquisando, e encontrei algo que pode ser o seguinte: Esse token quem esta me retornando é a Azure, e devo pegar o token do facebook e na hora de fazer a listagem da api, enviar o token do facebook... mas ainda não testei. Faz sentido?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que está participando da Maratona Xamarin. Para pegar os dados do perfil fiz da seguinte forma:

```
public class AzureService
{
    List<AppServiceIdentity> identities = null;
    public MobileServiceClient Client { get; set; } = null;
    .....
}
```

---

```
......
identities = await Client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");
var name = identities[0].UserClaims.Find(c => 
c.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")).Value; 

var userToken = identities[0].AccessToken; 

var requestUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/?fields=picture&access_token={userToken}";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var userJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);

var facebookProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookProfile>(userJson)
......
```

Fonte:
https://github.com/rubgithub/JogoDaVelhaMaratonaXamarin/blob/master/JogoDaVelhaMaratona/JogoDaVelhaMaratona/Service/AzureService.cs

Comment: Segui suas dicas, porem ainda não consegui resolver. Ao tentar utilizar o httpCliente para um getAsync na minha url https://adoteumamigo.azurewebsites.net/api/Tipo depois de logado com o facebook, continuo recebendo o código 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: e sim, estou fazendo a maratona sim, e seguindo os passos dos vídeos, porem ao fazer o login com facebook, e tentar utilizar uma api (q esta hospedada na azure) para listar itens estou tendo este problema.

Comment: Você está utilizando o token obtido aqui? `identities = await Client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");`

Comment: estou sim. E ai me entra outra dúvida, eu posso ta fazendo algo errado na hora q eu faço o getAsync aqui var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{BaseUrl}Tipo").ConfigureAwait(false);